# How to deal with the FPS drop on Web when I execute render by three.js and the model.predict() by tensorflow.js in the same frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, tensorflow.js

When I use tensorflowjs to predict the model，and then render to canvas.
But once the function predict executed,the FPS drop occurs, causing causing the screen to jam.

**Q：Tensorflowjs model prediction and threejs rendering are performed in each frame, but I found that the renderer.render function will not be executed until the model prediction ends, so that FPS reduction, jamming, etc. will occur.
Is there any way to improve this result?**

```
animation();

function animation()
{
requestAnimationFrame(animation)
predict(tf.fromPixels(albedo), tf.fromPixels(direct), model, INPUT_NODE_NAME, OUTPUT_NODE_NAME);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function predict(albedo,direct,model,INPUT_NODE_NAME,OUTPUT_NODE_NAME) {
            console.time("1111");
            const y=tf.tidy(() => {
                const PREPROCESS_DIVISOR = tf.scalar(255 / 2);
                const preprocessedInputAlbedo = tf.div(
                tf.sub(albedo.asType('float32'), PREPROCESS_DIVISOR),
                PREPROCESS_DIVISOR);
                const preprocessedInputDirect = tf.div(
                tf.sub(direct.asType('float32'), PREPROCESS_DIVISOR),
                    PREPROCESS_DIVISOR);

                const reshapedInputAlbedo =preprocessedInputAlbedo.reshape([1, ...preprocessedInputAlbedo.shape]);
                const reshapedInputDirect =preprocessedInputDirect.reshape([1, ...preprocessedInputDirect.shape]);

                const imageConcat=tf.concat([reshapedInputAlbedo,reshapedInputDirect],3);

                var output=model.predict(
                    {[INPUT_NODE_NAME]: imageConcat}, OUTPUT_NODE_NAME);
                output=tf.mul(
                    tf.add(output, 1),
                    PREPROCESS_DIVISOR).toInt();
                output=output.reshape([512,512,3]);
                console.timeEnd("1111");
                return output;

            });
            tf.toPixels(y,document.getElementById("tensorflow"));
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with tensorflow but if the output of your `model.predict` is what needs to be rendered with three.js then the render function should wait for your `model.predict` to finish.

Again, I'm not familiar with tensorflow. If some of your code can be executed in parallel, then it might be worth looking into [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: maybe I want to no how to execute in parallel?

Comment: Can you share your predict function?

Comment: above code is correct

Comment: can you share the github repository if it's not a problem?

Comment: There are things incomplete in the code that makes it difficult to answer your question. What is scene, what is camera ? If possible could you please use stackblitz.com or codepen.com to share your code so that we can easily have a look at it and see what is going wrong